# Not able to click on element although click in not throwing error

Tags: java, selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on webelement even though click () is not throwing error.

I tried javascript executor as well and not a wait issue since I have added Thread.sleep()

```
WebElement del = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='userAddressList']/li[1]/dl/../div[2]/a"));   
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", del);
```

`del.isDisplayed() and del.isenabled() returns true.`

**NOTE**: This is an SVG element with default xpath as

`.//*[@id='userAddressList']/li[1]/div[2]/a/svg`

But then I use this I was getting

> unable to locate element error

Comment: can you try something like `.//*[@id='userAddressList']/li[1]/div[2]/a/*[@name='svg']`

Comment: Can you show us `HTML` of target element?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj : it is not working

Comment: @Andersson : How can I show you that ?

Comment: @AaryaHareendranath, update (edit) your question with appropriate code sample

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj your tip worked able to locate with slight variation .//*[@id='userAddressList']/li[1]/div[2]/a/*[local-name()='svg']

Comment: Fine!! Glad it worked!!

Comment: You should post an answer to help others in the future ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably also achieve it using `*[@name='x:svg']` in your XPATH.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I used. A slight variation from Sudharshan's answer

```
.//*[@id='userAddressList']/li[1]/div[1]/a/*[local-name()='svg']
```